# What distribution should be used to model at least 1 "hit" in n trials where the probability of each hit is not constant for each trial?

Tags: distributions, monte-carlo

Obviously the first things that came to mind were binomial/geometric/beta binomial distributions but these all assume probability of hits are constant.

As an example to try and illustrate what I am looking for:

Probability at least 1 hit in 1 trial where for each trail where 
p(success trial 1)= 0.001

Probability of at least 1 hit in 2 trials where 
p(success trial 1)=0.001 
p(trial success trial 2)=0.002

Probability of at least 1 hit in 3 trials where

p(success trial 1)=0.001 
p(success trial 2)=0.002 
p(success trial 3)=0.005

So essentially probability of each nth hit would be a function of the the number of trials.

This is for use in a monte carlo simulation which will take the number of trials as an input.

Comment: The Dirichlet distribution is considered a distribution of distributions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

Comment: In your example, assuming independent trials, P(No Hit) = (.999)(.998)(.995) and P(At least one hit) = 1 - P(No Hit) =   0.00798301.

Comment: @BruceET But what distribution would capture this? If we had (.999)(.999)(.999) then this would be captured by a binomial distribution but because probability is increasing as a function of trials we can't use that unfortunately.

Comment: I know of no name for a dist'n consisting of $n$ Bernoulli trials with different success probabilities. There is the general principle that $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$ for independent events in same sample space.